# sql query cross tab

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a db with the following tables:

customer_info table with the following columns:

```
custID | storeName     | accName
  1    |  bayport      | name one
  2    |  plainfield   | name two
  3    |  bayport      | name three
```

deals table with the following columns:

```
dealID | dealDate     | custID
  1    | 2012-10-15   |   1
  2    | 2012-11-25   |   2
  3    | 2012-12-17   |   3
  4    | 2012-12-17   |   1
```

phone_details table with the following columns

```
phone_ID  | instore  | online  | received | dealID  
    1     |    1     |    0    |    0     |   1
    2     |    1     |    0    |    0     |   1
    3     |    0     |    1    |    1     |   1    
    4     |    0     |    1    |    0     |   2
    5     |    0     |    1    |    0     |   3
    6     |    0     |    1    |    1     |   3
    7     |    1     |    0    |    1     |   4
    8     |    1     |    0    |    1     |   4
```

invoice_details

```
payment_ID   | due  | paid | tender | dealID
      1      | 1000 | 500  | cash   |    1    
      2      | 500  | 100  | credit |    2 
      3      | 200  | 200  | cash   |    3 
      4      | 350  | 350  | debit  |    4
```

How can I query this table so that my result will look like this for a certain date?

For example, 2012-10-15 - 2012-11-25 it would look like this

```
               | bayport |   plainfield 
# of instore   |    2    |       0
# of online    |    1    |       1
total          |    3    |       1
# of received  |    1    |       0
total amount   |  1000   |      500
```

Comment: What RDMS are your using?   Microsoft SQL, mySQL, Oracle?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, I am using MySQL

Comment: Oh, because that's just the start of my query there are additional fields I need to add and total to that and those tables are just an excerpt of the full table. With the amount of data I need to add its easier to see the result if the storeName are used as columns

Comment: it was a typo. I edited it again to add another table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to contrast with [@MichaelBerkowski's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14149976), if you could tolerate the data oriented with bayport/plainfield as rows and instore/online as columns (per [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149902/sql-query-cross-tab/14150113#comment19598021_14149902) above), you can simply do:

```
SELECT    c.storeName,
          SUM(p.instore) AS `# of instore`,
          SUM(p.online ) AS `# of online`
FROM      customer_info c
LEFT JOIN deals         d
       ON d.custID    = c.custID
      AND d.dealDate  = '2012-10-15'
LEFT JOIN phone_details p USING (dealID)
GROUP BY  storeName
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d288b/1/0).

Comment: Yes, this would be the more typical output. Requires fewer tricks and hacks.

Comment: thanks eggyal, I edited my post to show more of what I wanted it to look like. Your query works awesome but the column heading are `# of instore` instead of the storeName, there is basically atleast 6 stores and the date of the query can be a specific date range

Comment: @ReneeCribe: Perhaps something like this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4ec0/1/0) will suffice?

Comment: yea i think ill just go with that, using the storename as a column name seems to be complicating things. thanks eggyal

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely an odd configuration.

This will require a `UNION ALL` which grabs the `online` and `instore` values for each to make them into rows rather than columns. That is then pivoted using a `SUM(CASE...)` to turn the store names into columns.

```
SELECT 
  calltype,
  /* In the outer query, pivot the storeName */
  SUM(CASE WHEN storeName = 'bayport' THEN num ELSE 0 END) AS bayport,
  SUM(CASE WHEN storeName = 'plainfield' THEN num ELSE 0 END) AS plainfield
FROM (
    /* First half gets the instore */
    SELECT
      /* String literal for label column */
      '# of instore' AS calltype,
      COUNT(*) AS num,
      storeName
    FROM
      customer_info c
      LEFT JOIN deals d ON c.custID = d.custID
      LEFT JOIN phone_details p ON d.dealID = p.dealID
    WHERE instore = 1 AND dealDate = '2012-10-15'
    GROUP BY storeName, calltype
    UNION ALL
    /* Second half gets the online */
    SELECT
      '# of online' AS calltype,
      SUM(online) AS num,
      storeName
    FROM
      customer_info c
      LEFT JOIN deals d ON c.custID = d.custID
      LEFT JOIN phone_details p ON d.dealID = p.dealID
    WHERE online = 1 AND dealDate = '2012-10-15'
    GROUP BY storeName, calltype
) totals 
GROUP BY calltype, storeName
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af18b/13